# How to delete selected file path from from db where 'implode' method was used when inserted

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new to Codeigniter and have managed to build an app where I have used 'implode' method to insert multiple files in db table in single column.

I am trying to figure out how to delete a single selected file from this column. I think I should be using something like 'Explode' or I am not sure.

In column files appear as:

> image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg,image4.jpg,image5.jpg

So far I have controller:

```
function property_image_delete() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $image = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $data['images_urls'] = $this->my_listings_model->get_property_all_images_url($id);
    $this->my_listings_model->delete_selected_property_image($id, $image, $data);
    $data['title'] = 'Image Deleted';
    $this->load->view('view');
```

url appear as:

> localhost/dashboard/property_image_delete/1/image.jpg

Model:

```
function delete_selected_property_image($id, $image, $data) {
    $this->db->select('property_images', $image);
    $this->db->where('property_ref_id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('vbc_property_images');
    unlink('uploads/property-images/'.$image);
    return TRUE;
}
function get_property_all_images_url($id) {
    $this->db->select('property_images');
    $this->db->from('vbc_property_images');
    $this->db->where('property_ref_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
$query_result = $query->result_array();
if (empty($query_result)) {
    return FALSE;
}
elseif (count($query_result) > 1) {
    return 0;
}
else{
    $rowId = explode(',',$query_result[0]['property_images']);
    return $rowId;
}
}
```

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#delete but I suggest never deleting for real and just adding another column with a boolean called `deleted`

Comment: for suppose if u want to delete image3.jpg this, than your remaining values in column should be image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image4.jpg,image5.jpg ??

Comment: @devpro, thats right.. this is what I would like to do.

Comment: @Thomas both codeigniter doc's now here http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your comments, i am sharing a basic idea for this, you can implement this with your CI Queries.

```
// a file that you want to delete.
$Delete = "image3.jpg";

// Existing Column Data , that you get from your DATABASE by using SELECT Query
$yourColumnValue = "image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg,image4.jpg,image5.jpg";

// explode with , you will get this data in an array
$explodeArr = explode(",", $yourColumnValue);

$updatedColumn = "";
foreach ($explodeArr as $key => $value) {
    if($value != $Delete){
        $updatedColumn[] = $value; // store data that you dont need to delete
    }
}
```

**What is the result of $updatedColumn:**

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($updatedColumn);

Array
(
    [0] => image1.jpg
    [1] => image2.jpg
    [2] => image4.jpg
    [3] => image5.jpg
)

// final updated data with comma seperated.
$newUpdatedData = implode(",", $updatedColumn);
```

**And the result of $newUpdateData should be:**

```
image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image4.jpg,image5.jpg
```

**Now Use CI UPDATE Statement:**

```
$this->db->where('property_ref_id', $id);
$this->db->update(array('vbc_property_images'=>$newUpdatedData));
```

**What should be happened?**

After this you don't need to `DELETE` any record, you can just update the existing record by using `UPDATE` Statement.

Comment: Hi @devpro,, `print_r($updatedColumn);` still echo the whole value including image3.jpg

Comment: @CodeIgniter_Learner: how ? are u checking my code or impplment suggestion in your code???

Comment: @CodeIgniter_Learner, yes checked, plz test by using this and show the result. $explodeArr = explode(",", "image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image3.jpg,image4.jpg,image5.jpg");
delete_selected_property_image(1,'image3.jpg',$explodeArr);

Comment: 'delete_selected_property_image' is not defined

Comment: oh my friend, u are using CI, u can call it as $this->delete_selected_property_image(param,,,,,,)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100582/discussion-between-devpro-and-codeigniter-learner).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In the controller:

```
function property_image_delete($id, $image) {    
    $this->my_listings_model->delete_selected_property_image($id, $image);
    $data['title'] = 'Image Deleted';
    $this->load->view('view');
}
```

Then in your model:

```
function delete_selected_property_image($id, $image) {
    //get the string of images names 
    $this->db->select('property_images');
    $this->db->where('property_ref_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('vbc_property_images');
    $result = $query->result();
    //turn the string into an array with explode
    $images_array = explode(',', $result->property_images);
    //find and remove the unwanted image name from the array
    if(($key = array_search($image, $images_array )) !== false) {
        unset($images_array [$key]);
    }
    //update the database with the imploded new array
    $this->db->where('property_ref_id', $id);
    $this->db->update(array('vbc_property_images'=>implode(',', $images_array)));
    //delete the file
    unlink("uploads/property-images/{$id}/{$image}");
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I have just updated my question in Controller with "$data['images_urls']".. If that makes a difference? because the one that I have in uri is single image path..

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
   function property_image_delete() {
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $image = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $data['images_urls'] = $this->my_listings_model->get_property_all_images_url($id);
        // $data['images_urls']  // <-- !!! is an array?
        $this->my_listings_model->delete_selected_property_image($id, $image, $data['images_urls']);
        $data['title'] = 'Image Deleted';
        $this->load->view('view');
     }
```

Update your model function!

```
 function delete_selected_property_image($id, $image,$urls) {
        $this->db->select('property_images', $image);
        $this->db->where('property_ref_id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('vbc_property_images');
        if ($query && $query->num_rows() > 0){
            $row = $quer->row();
            $images = explode(',',$row->property_images);
            if(($key = array_search($image, $images)) !== false) {
                unset($images[$key]);
                unlink($urls[$image]); // <--- **EDITED**
            }
            else
                return false;
            $images = implode(',',images);
            $data = array(
                'property_images' => $images
            );
            $this->db->where('property_ref_id', $id);
            $this->db->update('vbc_property_images',$data);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I have just updated my question in Controller with "$data['images_urls']".. If that makes a difference? because the one that I have in uri is single image path..

Comment: Say for "Message: Use of undefined constant image - assumed 'image'" `unlink($urls[image]);`.. By the way please check my addition to controller and model in the question..

Comment: Correct..its an array